# Cant Import Model in the views

Tags: python, django

I am following [this](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/dynamic_data_in_templates/) tutorial to learn django.

I wanted to list the product in the view, here is my **/product/views.py** file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def product_list(request):
    products = "Motorola"#Product.objects.order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, "product_list.html", {'products':products})
```

without model import it works well. but,
when I try to import the models in view file(/product/views.py) like

```
from .models import Product
```

here is my /product/urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from views import product_page, product_list, home_page

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_page, name="Home Page"),
    url(r'^products/', product_list, name="ProductRoot"),
]
```

it gives me below error.

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I have looked for the similar questions but got no help from that.

can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What were you doing when you got the error?

Comment: You're importing `views` somewhere where you shouldn't, maybe in settings or so.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes, let me edit my question

Comment: @RemcoGerlich edited , how to overcome?

Comment: @Sayse, I was searching on stackoverflow for the solution, and applying in my app. :)

Comment: Still normal, do you import urls from somewhere? The problem is models can't get imported before Django is done with configuring, e.g. while it's reading settings. Importing views from urls.py and models from views.py is perfectly normal.

Comment: Do you import things in settings, or in `__init__.py`?

Comment: So you were searching for a solution before you even got the error? interesting foresight....Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @RemcoGerlich oh my god! yes. thanks! it resolved. can you explain me why it is throwing error if I import in __init__.py file?

Comment: Because `__init__` is loaded when anything is imported from the package, so it is loaded when Django imports settings.py, so then the chain of imports starts and you aren't allowed to import models.py at that point.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have imported the `urls` in the `__init__.py` file which was my mistake,

After removing the `urls` import from the `__init__.py` file and resolved the error.